# Laravel jqgrid integrated

Tags: laravel, jqgrid

I'm trying to integrated jqgrid into Laravel for week, the only package I found is Mgallegos's, unfortunate, it is too complicate for newbie like me to learning.Here are my code, any help would be great appreciate
**Route**

```
Route::post('/test',array('as'=>'ajax.test','uses'=>'TestController@getTestData'));
```

**model**

```
class People extends Eloquent
      { 
        public $timestamps = false; 
        protected $table = "people"; 
        protected $guarded = array("*"); 
        protected $fillable = array("Name", "Age", "RecordDate"); 
      }
```

**TestController**

```
Class TestController extends BaseController {    
    public function getTestData()    
    {    
        $companies = People::all();    
        return Response::json($companies);    
    }    
}
```

**View Test.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>jQGrid example</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css' />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery-ui-custom.min.js'></script>        
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        // prepare the data
            var source ={
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: [{ name: 'id' },{ name: 'Name' },{ name: 'Age' },,],
                url: '{{ URL::route("ajax.test") }}'
            };
            $("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
                source: source,
                theme: 'classic',
                columns: [
                  { text: 'id', datafield: 'id', width: 250 },
                  { text: 'Name', datafield: 'Name', width: 150 },
                  { text: 'Age', datafield: 'Age', width: 180 }
                ]
            });
        });

        <div id="jqgrid"></div>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

These code give me error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException
What I really need is tutorial or working code which cover route/controller/model/view to follow up.I'm using Laravel 4.1.30.
Thank advanced
with route

```
Route::get('/test',array('as'=>'ajax.test','uses'=>'TestController@getTestData'));  

+--------+---------------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI           | Name      | Action                     | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+---------------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD test | ajax.test | TestController@getTestData |                |               |
+--------+---------------+-----------+----------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: try `Route::get('/test',array('as'=>'ajax.test','uses'=>'TestController@getTestData'));`

Comment: **Not work**,  it return: Method [getTestData] does not exist

Comment: do some basic debugging. what does `php artisan routes` outputs?

Comment: artisan routes: get|head test ajax.test TestController@getTestData

Answer (score 0):

Here are two recommendation that might help:

- Make sure you are using the right Javascript method, Trirand JqGrid uses the method `.jqgrid` and your using the method `.jqxGrid` which is a completely different plugin.
- The method `getTestData()` should return the data as the plugin is expecting it, you can't just return the data. Take a look at this example from the official JqGrid page where you can see how the data should be returned: http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html  (Loadind data -> JSON data)

Comment: Hi guys: thank for your response. I think there are 3 issues in my case, A. jqgrid not jqxgrid B.MethodNotAllowedHttpException C.Need response with jqgrid expect data. I look at the demo code that you mention many times, my problem is: Need a integrated working sample as a absolute newbie like me. I have very little chance to handle more than one issue at the same time (I have 2 here, issue A was easiest to fix)

Comment: I know is a little bit late, but if you're still interested maybe the following tutorials might help you: http://goo.gl/4Zlynt